# I don't what's going on with arrays in eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, syntax

I have a problem in Eclipse with writing an array:

```
public class nizovi {
    int[] anArray;
    anArray = new int[10];

}
```

Eclipse says:

> "Syntax error on token ";" ,, expected"

As you can see, it looks perfectly fine. I don't know what is going on with it.

Comment: You forgot to put the code in a block

Answer (score 4):

If you want to assign a value on class level, you must do it in one line:

```
public class nizovi {
    int[] anArray = new int[10];

}
```

Comment: Or use an (instance) initializer block. Or assign within constructor...

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you initialise your array in a constructor this way :

```
public class Nizovi {
    int[] anArray ;
    public Nizovi(){
        this.anArray = new int[10];
    }
}
```